# AWS Glue does not detect partitions and creates 1000+ tables in catalog

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I am using AWS Glue to create metadata tables.

AWS Glue Crawler data store path: s3://bucket-name/

Bucket structure in S3 is like

```
├── bucket-name        
│   ├── pt=2011-10-11-01     
│   │   ├── file1                    
|   |   ├── file2                                        
│   ├── pt=2011-10-11-02               
│   │   ├── file1          
│   ├── pt=2011-10-10-01           
│   │   ├── file1           
│   ├── pt=2011-10-11-10              
│   │   ├── file1
```

for this aws crawler create 4 tables.

My question is why aws glue crawler does not detect partition?

Answer (score 7):

To force Glue to merge multiple schemas together, make sure this option is checked, when creating the crawler -
**Create a single schema for each S3 path.**

[Screenshot of crawler creation step, with this setting enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyAmc.png)

Here's a detailed explanation - quoting directly, from AWS documentation ([reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/crawler-configuration.html#crawler-grouping-policy))

> By default, when a crawler defines tables for data stored in Amazon S3, it considers both data compatibility and schema similarity. Data compatibility factors taken into account include whether the data is of the same format (for example, JSON), the same compression type (for example, GZIP), the structure of the Amazon S3 path, and other data attributes. Schema similarity is a measure of how closely the schemas of separate Amazon S3 objects are similar.
>
> You can configure a crawler to CombineCompatibleSchemas into a common table definition when possible. With this option, the crawler still considers data compatibility, but ignores the similarity of the specific schemas when evaluating Amazon S3 objects in the specified include path.
>
> If you are configuring the crawler on the console, to combine schemas, select the crawler option Create a single schema for each S3 path.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but it's better to add context around the link and quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable.

Comment: @youssef - thanks for your feedback on my first ever answer :). Kindly let me know if this edit is sufficient

Answer (score 3):

Need to crawl a parent folder with all partition under it, otherwise the crawler will treat each partition as a seperate table.  So example, create as such

```
s3://bucket/table/part=1
s3://bucket/table/part=2
s3://bucket/table/part=3
```

then crawl  s3://bucket/table/

Answer (score 1):

Answer is:

Aws glue crawler before merging schema, first find similarity index of the schema(s). If similarity index is more than 70% then merge otherwise create a new table.

Comment: Is there any documentation about that? I would appreciate any link with details.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things I needed to do to get AWS Glue to avoid creating extraneous tables. This was tested with boto3 1.17.46.

Firstly, ensure an S3 object structure such as this:

```
s3://mybucket/myprefix/mytable1/<nested_partition>/<name>.xyz
s3://mybucket/myprefix/mytable2/<nested_partition>/<name>.xyz
s3://mybucket/myprefix/mytable3/<nested_partition>/<name>.xyz
```

Secondly, if using boto3, create the crawler with the arguments:

```py
targets = [{"Path": f"s3://mybucket/myprefix/mytable{i}/"} for i in (1, 2, 3)]
config = {"Version": 1.0, "Grouping": {"TableGroupingPolicy": "CombineCompatibleSchemas"}}

boto3.client("glue").create_crawler(Targets={"S3Targets": targets}, Configuration=json.dumps(config))
```

- As per [`Targets`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.create_crawler), each table's path is provided as a list to the crawler.
- As per [`Configuration`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/crawler-configuration.html), all files under each provided path should be merged into a single schema.

If using something other than boto3, it should be straightforward to provide the aforementioned arguments similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use table path like `s3://bucket-name/<table_name>/pt=<date_time>/file`.
If after that a Crawler treat every partition like separate table, try to create the table manually and re-run Crawler to bring partitions.